# About the default value issue in UAAppReviewManager

Tags: ios, uaappreviewmanager

I just wondering where the default value setting?

**UAAppReviewManager.h**

```
/*
 * Get/Set your Apple generated software id.
 * This is the only required setup value. No default.
 */
+ (NSString *)appID;
+ (void)setAppID:(NSString *)appID;

/*
 * Get/Set the App Name to use in the prompt
 * Default value is your localized display name from the info.plist
 */
+ (NSString *)appName;
+ (void)setAppName:(NSString *)appName;

/*
 * Get/Set the title to use on the review prompt.
 * Default value is a localized "Rate <appName>"
 */
+ (NSString *)reviewTitle;
+ (void)setReviewTitle:(NSString *)reviewTitle;

/*
 * Get/Set the message to use on the review prompt.
 * Default value is a localized 
 *  "If you enjoy using <appName>, would you mind taking a moment to rate it? It won't take more than a minute. Thanks for your support!"
 */
```

Above is a piece of code in UAAppReviewManager.h and it says that default value is your localized display name from the info.plist,

**But I didn't find any info.plist including those setting(Default value)**

So where's it?

Answer (score 1):

It is referring to your project info .[image]

Comment: As the author of UAAppReviewManager, I can say this is the correct answer.